# FYI: proposed site for "agriculture"

Tags: discussion

Those interested in gardening on a larger scale might want to look at the recently proposed site:
[Agriculture - Area 51 - Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127654/agriculture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, we get questions that might be in scope for that site three or four times a year.  Hope the proposal succeeds!